# InputSource text encoding

Tags: java, android, encoding

I have a problem with the encoding of the text. Downloading and parses the xml file. Here, everything works as it should, but the text in the xml file is stored using the encoding ISO-8859-2. To be able to download the file I am using is.setEncoding ("ISO-8859-1") I can not take advantage of is.setEncoding ("ISO-8859-2"), because I get the error coding.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the XML text is in ISO-8859-2, but the XML either has no **encoding** (defaults to UTF-8) or a wrong `encoding="UTF8"` (probably). This goes wrong if you immediately load it as XML. So you have to load it as text, with **ISO-8859-2**, and then pass it to the XML API. (Using ISO-8859-1 is not needed or helpful.)

- Read it as ISO-8859-2 text
- Pass a string to XML

Comment: Maybe delete the encoding attribute from the string before passing it to XML.

Comment: The problem is hear: InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(xmlUrl.openStream());
   inputSource.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

Comment: OK I found solusion: 

    String coding = new String(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-2");